# java unmodifiableMap with enum as values "loses" values

Tags: java, dictionary, enums

I've got a strange problem. I have a java class which looks like this:

```
public class VagueDate {
  private static String DAY = "D";
  private static String TO_YEAR = "-Y";

  public enum Type {
    DAY(VagueDate.DAY), TO_YEAR(VagueDate.TO_YEAR);

    private String string;

    private Type(String string) {
      this.string = string;
    }

    public String getStringRepresentation() {
      return string;
    }  
  }

  public static final Map<String, Type> typeMapping;
  static {
    HashMap<String, Type> myMap = new HashMap<String, Type>();
    myMap.put(DAY, Type.DAY);
    myMap.put(TO_YEAR, Type.TO_YEAR);

    typeMapping = Collections.unmodifiableMap(myMap);
   };

  private LocalDate startDate;
  private LocalDate endDate;
  private Type type;

  public VagueDate(LocalDate start, LocalDate end, Type type) {
    this.startDate = start;
    this.endDate = end;
    this.type = type;
  }

  public VagueDate(LocalDate start, LocalDate end, String dateType) {
    this(start, end, typeMapping.get(dateType));
  }

// getter, setter, etc
}
```

Everythink seems to work fine, I can create VagueDate objects with both constructors. But when I use the class in a webapp, sometimes a strange thing happens: the map typeMapping looks after some time like this: "D" -> null, "-Y" -> null .
If this happen once, it stays like this.

How can entries in an unmodifable map be modified? Or is it not allowed to use enums as a map value?

Regards

Daniel

Comment: "looses" -> "loses", please. "loose" is the opposite of "tight", not the opposite of "gain".

Comment: It is happening because static block executed before enum initialization.

Comment: @Orion but why is it then working for test cases, and for some time deployed in a webcontainer?

Comment: @Orion how can static block be executed before the static enum?

Comment: @Orion all enum constants are static. And if they would not be static you would get a compiler error in static block.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the server serializes and de-serializes your unmodifiable map? Since your enum is not serializable, it would not be restored. I have seen similar errors on a tomcat instance.

To test this, either define your map as transient or make your enum serializable.

Comment: static fields are not serializable per default

Comment: @llogiq If tomcat should try to serialize something which is not working, should there not be some SerializationException in the log?

Comment: @dve: As far as I recall, in my case, it was not showing anything, neither in catalina.out nor in localhost.log. Note that this was over 2 years ago, so I may be wrong.